# Sorting alghoritm time complexity for array in array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

So this one really puzzled me hard and put me in a bad spot! If we have an array similar to an matrix where we have (n) amount of columns, but now for the tricky part we have something else or equal to (n) amount of rows lets call that (m)!

In this case we have to search n*m amount of indexes, I do know that if we both rows and columns were equal n*n it would simply be O(n^2), but in my case with n*m would the worst case be O(n*m) or still O(n^2). The reason my brain isn't grasping this is that O(n*m) is a linear function whereas the other is exponential, but what if (m) was equal or more than (n)? then it should take equal amount of time or even longer to complete the task... So what am I actually missing here? :O

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: Either m is a constant or m grows. If m grows with the size of n then (m x n) isn't linear. Unless you know how m and n are related the best you can say is O(n x m).

Comment: O(n^2) is not *exponential*. It is *quadratic*. O(2^n) would be exponential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the value of `m` and `n`. if you don't have any bound for `m` and `n` the complexity of `O(nm)` is more explainable than `O(n^2)`.

If there is a bound for `m` (or `n`) you can apply this upper bound in the complexity term to simplify it. For example, if you know `m` is constant, you can say the complexity is `O(n)`. Or the upper bound for `m` is `n^2`, the simpler form of the complexity is `O(m sqrt(m))` (or `O(n^3)`).

Notice that, in the last case, it would be better to write `O(mn)` unless `m = \Theta(n^2)`. In the other words, in this case that you have an upper bound for `m`, to state more explainable complexity, it would be better write `O(mn)`, unless you have a tight lower bound proportional to the upper bound and this relation can be explained by `Theta` notation (as you found in the above example).